# add kafka autoStartUp false in the ConsumerConfig

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

how to add kafka property autoStartUp false manualy at property lvl ? what i mean, for example i can do it like that:

@KafkaListener(autoStartUp = "false")

but i wanna do it in the ConsumerProperties, in the own BeanPostProcessor. I could't find this property in the ConsumerProperties for example:

Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

```
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.kafkaConfig.getBootstrapServers());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    //here i need to add autoStartUp to false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `autoStartup` has nothing to do with Apache Kafka. It is native Spring container feature: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor. So, even if it would be possible via your `props`, it would not sound reasonable and felt more like abusing of Apache Kafka config with options which are not going to be parsed by Kafka mechanisms.

What you need is really pay more attention to that `autoStartup` option JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Set to true or false, to override the default setting in the container factory. May
 * be a property placeholder or SpEL expression that evaluates to a {@link Boolean} or
 * a {@link String}, in which case the {@link Boolean#parseBoolean(String)} is used to
 * obtain the value.
 * <p>SpEL {@code #{...}} and property place holders {@code ${...}} are supported.
 * @return true to auto start, false to not auto start.
 * @since 2.2
 */
String autoStartup() default "";
```

and look more in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation

So, roughly speaking, if you add an `autoStartUp` into your `props` bean, you can configure your `@KafkaListener` like this:

```
@KafkaListener(autoStartUp = "#{props.autoStartUp}")
```

Comment: thanks, it's a good idea, but if i haven't access to @KafkaListener? That's why i asked about properties or how to do it with other way

Comment: Well, otherwise it is also possible via a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` which is provided for that `@KafkaListener`. But if you don't have access to that one as well, you can't do that at all. You probably need to ask the team who developed that library for you to give access to those option on `@KafkaListener`.